# How to get raw sql with binds in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to find a way to get raw SQL with binds.

The following works with Sequelize model:

```
let conditions = {
   color: { [Sequelize.Op.in]: ['blue', 'yellow'] },
   type: 'active'
};

let options = { limit: 10 };

let sql = await sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery('widgets',
{
  where: conditions,
  ...options    
});
```

the above outputs

```
SELECT * 
FROM "widgets" 
WHERE "widgets"."color" IN ('blue', 'yellow') AND "widgets"."type" = 'active' 
LIMIT 10;
```

How can we get sql with binding for raw SQL query?

```
sequelize.query(`
SELECT * 
FROM widgets
WHERE color IN (:colors)
`, 
{
  raw: true,
  type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
  replacements: {
    colors: ['blue', 'yellow']
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We can generate where clause by using sequelize `getWhereConditions` method

```
let sql = await sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.getWhereConditions(
      conditions,
      'widgets',
    );
```